# openCV Cascade Classifier rectangle box and its 4 coordinates

Tags: opencv, coordinates

I am trying to figure rectangle coordinates (4 points) that comes up when a object or face is detected using Cascade Classifier

I am using python and the code is based on the widely available sample:

```py
import cv2
custom_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')


def find_face(img):
    to_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    object_detected = custom_cascade.detectMultiScale(to_gray, 1.4, 4)

    for (x, y, w, h) in object_detected:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 1)

        # NOTE
        # Circle coordinate shows start of the corner (very top left)
        # Need to find all four coordinate of the rectangle
        cv2.circle(img, (x, y), 2, (0, 255, 0), 2)

        return x, y, w, h
```

How i can get the pixel coordinates and manipulate it? Is it the same with x + w & y + h or some way around. What if i need to find centroid of an object?

Comment: Where is the code you are using ? Which language you are using ? Please edit the question...

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk - Thanks for the correction.I have updated as requested

Answer (score 1):

if you want to find centroid change this line `cv2.circle(img, (x, y), 2, (0, 255, 0), 2)` to this
`cent_x = int( x+w/2)   cent_y = int(y+h/2)   cv2.circle(img, (cent_x,cent_y), 2, (0, 255, 0), 2)`

Comment: @pravot - (x+w/2, y+h/2) leads to 'integer arguement expected,got float'.

Comment: And its not inside the rectangle as well

Comment: Provided Your x,y should be top left corner

Comment: Thank you. I used abs() and converted to Int. X & Y (0,0) is at top left corner. Still not inside the rectangle

Comment: Top left (x,y) should be your bounding box coordinates and not (0,0) which is image top left.....use x,y used in cv2.reactangle

Answer (score 1):

`(x, y)` are the top left coordinates of the rectangle drawn by `cv2.rectangle`. `w` is the width and `h` is the height
You can manipulate that value to get the midpoint

or another way you can use `cv2.boundingRect (cnt)`

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys,

After brushing up my openCV and maths a bit and went through some docs, this one works:

```
center_point_x = abs(x + 0.5 * w)
center_point_y = abs(y + 0.5 * h)

cv2.circle(img, (int(center_point_x), int(center_point_y)), 2, (255, 0, 255), 2)
```

There is possibilities to use numpy as well. But i did a quick one to check for the operation. Hopefully this will help others.

Thank you all.